# Redshift: UPDATE statement using a LEFT JOIN returns "table name specified more than once" error

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, join, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have an UPDATE statement in Redshift that I'd like to use the LEFT JOIN method to identify records that don't exist in the second table. The statement keeps returning the *"table name specified more than once"* error. I understand I can use different methods such as NOT IN with a subquery but I'd like to learn how can I adapt this script in PostgreSQL using LEFT JOIN approach. Thank you in advance.

```
UPDATE A  
   SET A.column_Name = 'Y' 

FROM tbl_A A
LEFT JOIN tbl_B B
ON A.Mathcing_Column_Name = B.Matching_Column_Name
WHERE B.Matching_Column_Name is NULL
```

Comment: Don't repeat the target table in the FROM clause (BTW: the above seems like Microsoft syntax)

Comment: Also you can't use `A.column_name`, per [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html): " Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1 is invalid"

Comment: Thanks. If I were to remove the target table in the FROM clause, can you help me with how the LEFT JOIN will be done? Or I should just dismiss the LEFT JOIN approach (as you mentioned, a popular technique in MS SQL) and just go by with "NOT EXISTS" or "NOT IN" and a subquery in Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. (it's working)

```
with temp AS
(
  SELECT A.* FROM tbl_A A
  LEFT JOIN tbl_B B
  ON A.Mathcing_Column_Name = B.Matching_Column_Name
  WHERE B.Matching_Column_Name is NULL
)
UPDATE tbl_A C  SET column_Name = 'Y' 
from temp D
where C.id=D.id
```

Comment: Thank you Mitko. If I understood correctly, the LEFT JOIN approach won't quite work in Redshift instead I should use the CTE method or EXISTS or IN clause.

Comment: The approach with LEFT JOIN is OK for me. I'm using it without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
UPDATE tbl_A A  
   SET column_Name = 'Y' 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM tbl_B B
                     WHERE A.Matching_Column_Name = B.Matching_Column_Name
                    );
```

Comment: You will want to change `A.column_Name` to `column_Name`.

Comment: I downvoted. Because the answer was plain wrong, and you didn't react to the comment.

Comment: Maybe I could. But there is also the part of conditioning. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: No I didn't. I try to always give someone a chance to correct an answer. The few times I  have down voted it is for an obvious wrong answer that was not corrected or taken down.